# Datatable : sort column with HTML elements

Tags: sorting, datatables

I'm trying to sort a column such as :

```
<td> <span class="badge badge-light">300 €</span>  jean-yves@gmail.com </td>
```

Where the content of the badge (300 €) is the amount I want to be used for the sort.

Without the badge, the sort is working without problem, but it doesn't seem to work with the badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### SOLUTION 1

See [`columns.type`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) option which you can set to `'html'` to have HTML tags removed for ordering and searching.

#### SOLUTION 2

Alternatively you can tell DataTables value you want to use for sorting using `data-` attributes, see [HTML5 data-* attributes - cell data](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html).

For example:

```
<td data-order="300"> <span class="badge badge-light">300 €</span>  jean-yves@gmail.com </td>
```

Comment: Solution 2 worked perfectly. Solution 1 blocked the sorting for some reason, thanks for your help.